# How to update the table when same record is inserted using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am developing POS application, I am retrieving product after searching the barcode (which is saved in database in product table), there is add Cart button on which I click will add the product details,price and quantity in order table in database and will show after adding to database, if I enter the same product then its price and quantity should be increased.

when I click on add cart  for the same product it's retrieving the records from Database  with updated quantity and price but it's adding new row instead of  updating existing row (because of append) is there any other way which I can create a table so that each time I don't have to append a new row.

[image: same quantity adding to a row instead of updating row]
The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(event){
    var barcode=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var product=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    var price=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
    var order={"barcodeid":barcode,"pname":product,"price":price,"qty":1}


    console.log(orderid);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',    
        url:'/pos/addproduct',
        dataType: "json",
        data:JSON.stringify(order),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:
            function(data){

            $.each(data,function(index,value){

                var row=$("<tr><td>"+value.oid+"</td>"+"<td>"+value.pname+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+value.qty+"</td>"+"<td>"+value.price+"</td>"+"<td>"
                        +value.barcodeid+"</td></tr>");
                $("#order").append(row).removeClass("hidden");

            })

        }
    })
});
})
```

and the order table is

```
<table id="order" class="hidden" align="center">
<tr>
<th>OrderId</th>
<th>ProductName</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Barcode</th>
</tr>
<tr >
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest that you create the table beforehand doing your ajax call. Then associate a unique id (uuid) to each product in your database. Then in your table each row would have an id matching the product's own uuid. In your success method, first try to get $(#uuid) : if it returns something, it means you already picked up this product before, just get the quantity cell (you could do that by putting a name attribute on the quantity td), otherwise just create a new row as you do today.(but with the id=uuid attribute on the tr, and a name="qtyCell" on the qty td.)

Comment: I want the table to be created only when someone clicks on Add cart button

Comment: why do you use a $.each in your success function ? what does your server put in a POST call return response ?

Comment: $.each is used to iterate over the response from server to print the table and from server order details is returned

Comment: Use [Kendo UI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui) for jQuery?  It's free and battle-tested for all these types of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I assume your answer from server is a json object giving an orderId (which is unique for the cart, i.e. it does not change session-wide), then for the required Added product :
 - its product name
 - the total price for this product orders only (i.e unit price * qty)
 - the quantity
 - the barcodeid

I created a jsfiddle to show you my idea : [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c3pgogan/1/)

it works quite as your own code, except that

- obviously since I have not your server, I used jsfiddle AJAX service to return what I assume your server returns at POST request
- as a consequence, server side data are handled through two global variables for orderId, and ordered quantities (for each product, that is why it is an object)
- in the success function, I look for a cell (td) matching "qty+barcode", if I find it, I update it and the total price cell (which id is "price"+barcode). If I do not find it, I create the row (this is your code) while setting appropriate ids for both quantity and price cells.

  The following snippet in SO does not work (since there is no AJAX service) please run it in the above jsfiddle link

```js
var qty={};
var orderId = 12;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a[id^=submit]").click(function(event){
    var barcode=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var product=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    var price=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
    var order={"barcodeid":barcode,"pname":product,"price":price,"qty":1}

    if (qty.hasOwnProperty(barcode)) {
      qty[barcode]++;
      qty[barcode] = 1;
    }
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',    
      url:'/echo/json/',
      dataType: "json",
      data://JSON.stringify(order),
      {
        json: JSON.stringify({
          oid: orderId,
          pname: product,
          price: parseFloat(price)*qty[barcode],
          qty:qty[barcode],
          barcodeid:barcode
        }),
        delay: 1
      },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success:function(data) {
          value = data
          var qtyItm = $("#qty"+value.barcodeid);
          if (qtyItm.length) {
            qtyItm.html(qty[barcode]);
            $("#price"+value.barcodeid).html(value.price);
          } else {
            var row=$("<tr><td>"+value.oid+"</td>"+"<td>"+value.pname+"</td>"+
              "<td id=\"qty"+value.barcodeid+"\">"+value.qty+"</td>"+
              "<td id=\"price"+value.barcodeid+"\">"+value.price+"</td>"+
              "<td>"+value.barcodeid+"</td></tr>");
            $("#order").append(row).removeClass("hidden");
          }
        },
      fail:function() {
          alert('problem')
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table align="center">
    <tr><th>Barcode</th><th>ProductName</th><th>Price</th><th>ADD</th></tr>
    <tr><td>97</td><td>johson</td><td>44.0</td><td><a href="#" id="submit97">Add</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>98</td><td>another product</td><td>10.0</td><td><a href="#" id="submit98">Add</a></td></tr>
  </table>

  <table id="order" align="center">
    <tr><th>OrderId</th><th>ProductName</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Barcode</th></tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Your idea works fine if i retrieve one record from database, but in case of list of records i have to use $.each for the records which is not to be updated

Comment: i made changes i iterated through all the objects and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be to create entire Table into JS without much interrupting your code..

JS Code ---

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        var barcode=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
        var product=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
        var price=$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
        var order={"barcodeid":barcode,"pname":product,"price":price,"qty":1}


        console.log(orderid);
        var TableData = "";


         $.ajax({
                type:'POST',    
                url:'/pos/addproduct',
                dataType: "json",
                data:JSON.stringify(order),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:
                    function(data){
TableData = TableData + '<table id="order"  align="center">'
        TableData = TableData + '<tr>';
        TableData = TableData + '<th>OrderId</th>';
        TableData = TableData + '<th>ProductName</th>';
        TableData = TableData + '<th>Quantity</th>';
        TableData = TableData + '<th>Price</th>';
        TableData = TableData + '<th>Barcode</th>';
        TableData = TableData + '</tr>';
                    $.each(data,function(index,value){
                        TableData = TableData + "<tr><td>"+value.oid+"</td><td>"+value.pname+"</td>";
                        TableData = TableData + "<td>"+value.qty+"</td>"+"<td>"+value.price+"</td>";
                        TableData = TableData + "<td>"+value.barcodeid+"</td></tr>";
                    })
 TableData = TableData + '</table>'
                }
            });


        $("#OrderDiv").html("");
        $("#OrderDiv").html(TableData);
});
})
```

and On HTML Replace

```
<table id="order" class="hidden" align="center">
<tr>
<th>OrderId</th>
<th>ProductName</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Barcode</th>
</tr>
<tr >
</table>
```

With

```
<div id = 'OrderDiv'> </div>
```

apply necessary CSS after success Request.

Answer (score 0):

i iterated through all the objects from database and checked whether the id is same as price and barcode if it is same update the price and quantity using their div elements

```
    function(data){
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                var temp = "qty" + data[index].barcodeid.trim();
                var qtyitm=$("#"+temp);
                if(qtyitm.length != 0){
                    qtyitm.html(data[index].qty);
                    //("#price"+(data[index].barcodeid.trim())).html(data[index].price);
                    temp = "price" + data[index].barcodeid.trim();
                    qtyitm = $("#"+temp);
                    qtyitm.html(data[index].price);
                }
                else{
                    var row=$("<tr><td>"+data[index].oid+"</td>"+"<td>"+data[index].pname.trim()+
                            "</td>"+
                            "<td id=\"qty"+data[index].barcodeid.trim()+"\">"+data[index].qty+"</td>"+
                            "<td id=\"price"+data[index].barcodeid.trim()+"\">"+data[index].price+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"
                            +data[index].barcodeid.trim()+"</td></tr>");

                    $("#order").append(row).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
            })

        }
```